# Git hook hack to workaround bad target branch when opening merge review on Gitlab

Tags: git, gitlab, hook, githooks

I  have the habit of creating merge requests (MR) by clicking the link printed by remote server on pushes :

```
╰─ git push
Counting objects: 33, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (33/33), done.
Writing objects: 100% (33/33), 3.46 KiB | 1.73 MiB/s, done.
Total 33 (delta 31), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: 
remote: To create a merge request for modelref, visit:
remote:   https://gitlab.com/foo/bar/merge_requests/new?merge_request%5Bsource_branch%5D=mybranch
```

Problem is that the target branch of the MR  will be set to the pre-configured `master` branch *

So basically I would prefer to have an url with the `merge_request%5Btarget_branch%5D=` url parameter set to the parent branch ([this script](https://gist.github.com/joechrysler/6073741) finds it).

I could write a local `pre-push` hook (as local `post-push` operations do not exist) that builds this url that I would click instead, but can you find a less ugly hack ?

---

*  <sub>which will result to a loss of time if I don't change the target branch immediatley as changing this form field reset all others fields (https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/22090)</sub>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I ended up doing :

*~/bin/git-branchestor.sh*

```
#!/bin/bash

# Find closest ancestor given two candidate branches

branch=`git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD`
commit1=`git merge-base $branch ${1}`
commit2=`git merge-base $branch ${2}`
ancestor=`git merge-base ${commit1} ${commit2}`
if [[ "$commit1" == "$ancestor" ]]; then
    echo ${2}
else
    echo ${1}
fi
```

My feature branches are branched off from either `hotfix` or `develop` ones, those are the arguments I give to my `git-branchestor.sh` script :

*.git/hooks/pre-push*

```
#!/bin/bash

remote="$1"
url="$2"

z40=0000000000000000000000000000000000000000

while read local_ref local_sha remote_ref remote_sha
do
    if [ "$local_sha" = $z40 ]
    then
        # Handle delete
        :
    else
        if [ "$remote_sha" = $z40 ]
        then
            # New branch, examine all commits
            range="$local_sha"
        else
            # Update to existing branch, examine new commits
            range="$remote_sha..$local_sha"
        fi
        branch=$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD)
        if [[ "$branch" != "hotfix" && "$branch" != "master" && "$branch" != "develop" ]]; then
          ancestor=`~/bin/git-branchestor.sh hotfix develop`
          echo "Open MR: https://gitlab.com/user/project/merge_requests/new?merge_request%5Bsource_branch%5D=${branch}&merge_request%5Btarget_branch%5D=${ancestor}"
          echo ""
        fi
    fi
done

exit 0
```